# Logitech t630 and GNOME shell

Tags: gnome, mouse-gestures

I'm using the Logitech t360 bluetooth mouse with GS 3.16. It work fine, but according to [this](http://www.logitech.com/assets/50008/t630-touch-gestures-guide.pdf) it should have various options for gestures (on windows).

In Linux, scrolling works fine and also two fingers left and right swipe works in chrome or nautilus for back and fwd navigation.

What I would like to achieve on linux is:

1. Tap: instead of left and right click, I would like to use tap
2. Overview mode: can I enable any of the available gestures for entering the overview mode (the one that is triggered by pressing the super key)?

Comment: These gestures are most likely tied to Windows drivers. You might want to look for Linux alternatives though.
Also, please rephrase your question so that it's clear what you're asking, and not you're "missing". It will make easier for others to correctly address your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I made some good progress.

First I used `xinput test "Ultrathin Touch Mouse"` to see what happens when iteracting with the mouse and I found out that:

- No input is provided by the mouse on single tap. So perhaps the mouse itself is not sending single taps
- When double tapping with two-fingers, the mouse sends a `char 134` `keydown` and `keyup` events

Char 134 is `Super_R` (right hand side Super key).
The I looked with `dconf-editor` into `/org/gnome/mutter/overlay-key` and I saw that is bound to `Super_L` (left hand side super key).
Now I had two options:

- **Option 1:** Change `/org/gnome/mutter/overlay-key` to `Super_R` and double tap with two-fingers on my mouse started working as desired (showing the overview mode). However that prevents Super_L to do the same. And since I'm on a laptop and I only have left hand super key, that solution is not very handy, so I went for
- **Option 2**: "Map" `Super_R` to `Super_L`:
- Install `xbindkeys` and `xdotool`
- Create `~/.xbindkeysrc` file and add the following:

`"xdotool key Super_L"`
    `c:134`

- Finally run (and also put in you startup items) `xbindkeys`

Basically, when I double tap with two fingers on my mouse, it sends a `Super_R` key press that is intercepted by `xbindkeys` that in turn simulates a `Super_L` keypress via `xdotool` as defined in `~/.xbindkeysrc` file.
I hope that this could help other people to better integrate their mouse gestures with their DE.